# Using session component in custom component

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

I'm trying to use Session component in custom component (CakePHP 2.3) but when I call Session component functions I get: Fatal error: Call to a member function read() on a non-object in ...\app\Controller\Component\CartComponent.php on line 7

My CartComponent looks like that:

```
<?php
App::uses('Component', 'Controller');
class CartComponent extends Component {
    public $components = array('Session');

    function hasItems() {
        $cart = $this->Session->read('Cart');
        return $cart != null && count($cart) > 0;
    }

}
?>
```

And I use it in controller:

```
<?php
class OrdersController extends AppController {
    public $name = 'Orders';
    public $components = array('Cart', 'Email');

    function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        if ($this->Cart->hasItems()) {
            $this->Auth->allow('add_item', 'remove_item', 'cart');
        } else {
            $this->Auth->allow('add_item', 'remove_item', 'cart', 'make');
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Why is the vital part (causing the fatal error) missing here in your code example?

Comment: I added missing part as you wish ;)

Comment: How do you load and use the CartComponent? That vital part is also missing - and most likely the source of the issue at hand.

Comment: I added also controller code in which I use CartComponent

Answer (score 8):

For using session inside the custom component I tried with

```
public $components = array('Session');
```

and then called it by using

```
$this->Session->read('Cart');
```

but I cant able to use it and I start to use

```
CakeSession::read('Cart')
```

Now it works Hope it will used for you note I used in cake php version > 2

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use Session in your Component Use-

```
$test = CakeSession::read('user'); 

print_r($test);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use as bellow

```
    class YourComponent extends Component {
     public function initialize(Controller $controller){
      $this->controller = $controller;
      if (!isset($this->controller->presetVars)) {
         $this->controller->presetVars = true;
      }

    $model = $this->controller->modelClass;
    if (!empty($settings['model'])) {
        $model = $settings['model'];
    }

    if ($this->controller->presetVars === true) {
        // auto-set the presetVars based on search definitions in model
        $this->controller->presetVars = array();
        $filterArgs = array();
        if (!empty($this->controller->$model->filterArgs)) {
            $filterArgs = $this->controller->$model->filterArgs;
        }

        foreach ($filterArgs as $key => $arg) {
            if ($args = $this->_parseFromModel($arg, $key)) {
                $this->controller->presetVars[] = $args;
            }
        }
    }
    foreach ($this->controller->presetVars as $key => $field) {
        if ($field === true) {
            if (isset($this->controller->$model->filterArgs[$key])) {
                $field = $this->_parseFromModel($this->controller->$model->filterArgs[$key], $key);
            } else {
                $field = array('type' => 'value');
            }
        }
        if (!isset($field['field'])) {
            $field['field'] = $key;
        }
        $this->controller->presetVars[$key] = $field;

   }
    /* now you can use Component existing in your Component :) */
    public function sayHello(){
     $this->controller->Session->setFlash(__('Hello you'));
    }

    }
```